# Is there any explicit symplectic Runge-Kutta method?

Tags: ode, runge-kutta

As far as I know, all the symplectic Runge-Kutta methods are implicit which need to solve non-linear equations during the calculation. Is there any explicit method? If not, why?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are explicit, symplectic methods for certain types of Hamiltonian problems. For example, the symplectic Euler method

\begin{align}
  p_{n+1} &= p_n - h H_q(p_{n+1}, q_n) \\
  q_{n+1} &= q_{n} + h H_p(p_{n+1}, q_n)
\end{align}

is symplectic, see e.g. Theorem 3.3 on p. 189 in the book by Hairer, Wanner and Lubich (see full reference below). For simple functions $H$ like $H(p, q) = \frac{1}{2} \left( p^2 + q^2 \right)$, this becomes

\begin{align}
  p_{n+1} &= p_n - h q_n \\
  q_{n+1} &= q_n + h p_{n+1}
\end{align}

which is explicit. More generally, this method is explicit for *separable* Hamiltonians (see comments after the Theorem mentioned above).

In VIII.6 on p. 325, Hairer et al state that

> Symplectic methods for general Hamiltonian equations are implicit, and so are symmetric methods for general reversible systems.

Therefore, there are no sympletic methods that are explicit for *general* Hamiltonian functions. I couldn't find the specific Theorem that states this, though.

*Hairer, Ernst; Lubich, Christian; Wanner, Gerhard*, [**Geometric numerical integration. Structure-preserving algorithms for ordinary differential equations**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/3-540-30666-8), Springer Series in Computational Mathematics 31. Berlin: Springer (ISBN 3-540-30663-3/hbk). xvii, 644 p. (2006). [ZBL1094.65125](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1094.65125).

Comment: Under most definitions I think the trivial "do nothing" method $p^{n+1}=p^n$, $q^{n+1}=q^n$ would count as an explicit symplectic method. It's a fairly awful one though

Comment: Given that this is not even consistent with the solved differential equation, I would doubt whether it can be called a "method" in any reasonable sense of the word.

Comment: `I couldn't find the specific Theorem that states this, though.` I believe the theorem you're looking for is in [section 2 of this paper by Sanz-Serna](http://www.sanzserna.org/pdf/56_physicaD.pdf), see also [these course notes, theorem 6](https://www.unige.ch/~hairer/poly_geoint/week2.pdf)

Comment: @GoHokies To be clear, the proof is sketched in Sanz-Serna's paper, where he also mentions that Lasagni gave a proof but didn't publish it.